# GLSL renders textures wrong

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, libgdx

I am trying to make a lighting system, the program changes the texture(block) brightness depends on the light it gets, and the program does it for every block(texture) that is visible to the player.

However, the lighting system works perfectly, but when it comes to rendering with shaders everything gets destroyed.

This code is in the render loop -

```
float light = Lighting.checkLight(mapPosY, mapPosX, this); // Returns the light the current block gets
map[mapPos].light = light; // Applies the light to the block
Shaders.block.setUniformf("lightBlock", light); // Sets the light value to the shader's uniform, to change the brightness of the current block / texture.

batch.draw(map[mapPos].TEXTURE, (mapPosX * Block.WIDTH), (mapPosY * Block.HEIGHT), Block.WIDTH, Block.HEIGHT); // Renders the block / texture to the screen.
```

The result is pretty random..
As i said the first two lines work perfectly, the problem is probably is in the third line or in the shader itself.

The shader:
Vertex shader -

```
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {
    vColor = a_color;
    vTexCoord = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position =  u_projTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0f);
}
```

Fragment shader -

```
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform vec2 screenSize;

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform float lightBlock;

const float outerRadius = .65, innerRadius = .4, intensity = .6;

const float SOFTNESS = 0.6;

void main() {

    vec4 texColor = texture2D(tex, vTexCoord) * vColor;

    vec2 relativePosition = gl_FragCoord.xy / screenSize - .5;

    float len = length(relativePosition);

    float vignette = smoothstep(outerRadius, innerRadius, len);

    texColor.rgb = mix(texColor.rgb, texColor.rgb * vignette * lightBlock, intensity);

    gl_FragColor = texColor;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? the question is fine..

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the uniform not being passed correctly to your fragment shader? Have you tried playing around with this variable (i.e.: hard coded values)? I don't no anything about libgdx, but your program seems to be pretty straight forward...

Comment: @PedroBoechat Yep, i played with the values for 2 days now, and it still seems like the uniform is not passed correctly to the fragment shader.. if you say that the shaders are fine it helps me a lot, because now i know where i shouldn't search for the fix.

Comment: Well, it seems to be OK according to old GLSL specs, and you're not getting compiling errors... but I guess it would be better to check semantic problems targeting a specific GLSL version (i.e.: adding #version 150 at the start of your shader sources)

Comment: @IsraelG.: If genpfault lost reputation for every question he downvoted, I think he would have 0 reputation by now ;) It is starting to get a bit annoying, though I do sort of agree in this case - some of the language in your question is highly unprofessional (not enough to merit a downvote, but still inappropriate).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.. but i dont have any idea why it fixed it.
Thanks to Pedro, i focused more on the render loop instead of the shader itself.

Before the loop i added those 2 lines -

```
List<Integer> lBlocks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Shaders.block.setUniformf("lightBlock", 0.3f);
```

Basically I created an array to store the bright blocks later on.
I set the uniform of the shader to be 0.3f which means pretty dark. the value should be 0-1f.

Now in the render loop, inside the for -

```
float light = Lighting.checkLight(mapPosY, mapPosX, this);
map[mapPos].light = light;
if( light == 1.0f) { 
    lBlocks.add(mapPos);
} else {
    batch.draw(map[mapPos].TEXTURE, (mapPosX * Block.WIDTH), (mapPosY * Block.HEIGHT), Block.WIDTH, Block.HEIGHT);
}
```

As you can see, the bright blocks i add to the array and the dark ones i render, i set the uniform to 0.3f before the render loop as you can in the first code sample.

After the render loop i loop again through the bright blocks.. because we didn't render them.

```
Shaders.block.setUniformf("lightBlock", 1.0f);
    for(int i = 0; i < lBlocks.size(); i++) {
        batch.draw(map[lBlocks.get(i)].TEXTURE, ((lBlocks.get(i) % width) * Block.WIDTH), ((lBlocks.get(i) / width) * Block.HEIGHT), Block.WIDTH, Block.HEIGHT);
    }
```

Now i rendered the bright blocks and it works.. the result was good.
But I don't have any idea why its like that, its like cutting the render loop to two, one for dark blocks and one for the bright ones.

Thanks :)